# Realm RecyclerView, How to create header by day. or merge same day in one row

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, realm

i have a 3 variable in activities realm object

```
int id;
String nameDay;
String toDoActivities;
```

i using `OrderedRealmObject` and `realmResult` for my `realmrecyclerview`.

this is my `onBindViewHolder`.

```
activities ac = activities.get(position);

holder.txtDay.setText(activities.getNameDay);
holder.txtToDo.setText(activities.getToDoActivities);
```

how to merge day if the day in realm is same. actually every day have more than 2 ToDoActivities.

Comment: You mean if one day has three data then it should be displayed in one row for particular that day?

Comment: ya, i mean like that.

Comment: i also want to get every id for the todoActivities. when i create with listview(for todoActivities) and put in to realmrecyclerview(for day). i so confused to get that id. because for listView i created with Arraylist from RealmResult

Comment: @Piyush now how to create row with particular day?

Answer (score 1):

For that check it by your adapter position

```
    if (position != 0) {
        if (activities.getNameDay.equalsIgnoreCase(activities.get(position-1).getNameDay)) {
            holder.rel_day.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.rel_day.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    } else {
        holder.rel_day.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Where `holder.rel_day` is your Layout in which your `TextView` for day will be there